# How to sort by nested object on mongodb via php?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I need help on how to sort a mongodb query based on a nested document

This is what i tried

```
$options = ['sort' => ['stats' => ['points' => 1]]];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([],$options);
```

This is the schema of the mongo object

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d0cd19c811d53277225fc33"),
    "uuid" : "a2277fa1-07df-4c19-902a-93ae7e2795a1",
    "name" : "ImAleex_",
    "stats" : {
        "points" : 1000,
        "kills" : 1,
        "losses" : 1,
        "wins" : 1
    },
    "info" : {
        "lastRankeds" : NumberLong(1561128665478),
        "lastConnection" : NumberLong(1561128834286),
        "lastModifiedKit" : NumberLong(1561215124553),
        "rankeds" : 5,
        "visibility" : true,
        "chat" : true,
        "fly" : false,
        "requests" : true,
        "menuRequests" : true
    }
}
```

I get this error message on Apache logs
ConnectionException: bad sort specification

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it , this is the correct syntax of the sort

`$options = ['sort' => ['stats.points' => 1]];`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$options = ['sort' => ['stats.points' => 1]];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([],$options);
```